# conditional probability markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

A man has three shirts. Each day he chooses one to wear at random from those that he was not wearing the previous day. The shirts are labelled by 1, 2 and 3 and X$_n$ is the label of the shirt he wears on day $n$.

What is the probability that the next day he will wear shirt 2 given that he wears shirt 1 today?

I look at this and the answer seems obvious, namely P(X$_{n+1}$ =2|X$_n$ =1) = $\frac{1}{2}$.

However the method presented uses the definition of conditional probability and is given as

P(X$_{n+1}$=2|X$_n$=1) = $\frac{P(X_{n+1}=2 \cap X_n=1)}{P(X_n=1)}$ = $\frac{1/3\times1/2}{1/3}=\frac{1}{2}$

What does $X_{n+1}=2 \cap X_n=1$ look like and why does it equal $\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2}$? Any feedback on this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A more solid explanation comes from the study of stationary distributions in Markov chains. Allow me a brief divagation.

Say we have a discrete Markov chain $X=\{X_n\}$ with space of possible states $S$ and transition matrix $P=(p_{xy})_{x,y\in S}$. A vector $\pi$ with non-negative entries is said to be a **stationary distribution** of $X$ if $\sum_{x\in S}\pi(x)=1$ and $\pi P = \pi$, that is if it satisfies $\pi(y) = \sum_{x\in S}p_{xy}\pi(x)$ for every $y\in S$

Let $\pi$ be a stationary distribution, then for every $n\in\mathbb N$
$$\pi P^n = (\pi P)P^{n-1} = \pi P^{n-1}=\ldots=\pi P = \pi$$
Thus, if $X$ has initial distribution $\pi$, for every $n\in\mathbb N$ we have that
$$\mathcal P(X_n=y)=\sum_{x\in X}\pi(x)p_{xy}^{(n)} =\sum_{x\in X}\pi(x)p_{xy}=\pi(y)$$

On the other hand, if the distribution of $X_n$ is independent of the time $n$, then the initial distribution $\pi_0$ is such that 
$$\mathcal \pi_0(y)= P(X_0=y) =\mathcal P(X_1=y)=\sum_{x\in S}\pi_0(x)p_{xy}$$ 
thus, $\pi_0$ is an stationary distribution.

In summary, the distribution of $X_n$ is independent of $n$ iff the initial distribution is a stationary distribution.

Now, let's get back to the man-shirt problem. As you've pointed out, it has transition matrix 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&0&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We're interested in finding $\pi$, its stationary distribution. That is, we solve a simple system of equations
$$\begin{align}
\pi(1) & = & 0 & +\frac12\pi(2) &+\frac12\pi(3)\\
\pi(2) & = &\frac12\pi(1)&+0&\frac12\pi(3)\\
\pi(3) & = &\frac12\pi(1)&+\frac12\pi(2)&+0\\
1 & = & \frac12\pi(1)&+\frac12\pi(2)&+\frac12\pi(3)
\end{align}
$$
which has solution $\pi=(\frac13,\frac13,\frac13)$. But the original problem states that the first day, the man chooses a shirt randomly. That is, the initial distribution is the stationary distribution. So $\mathcal P(X_n=y)=\frac13$ for $y=1,2,3$ and for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Now, getting back to your question, what does $\mathcal P(X_{n+1}=2, X_n=1)$ mean? It is the probability that the man wore the 1st shirt the $n$-th day AND he wore the 2nd shirt the next day. The probability of choosing the 1st shirt the $n$-th day is $\mathcal P(X_n=1) =\frac13$, and the probability that then he wore the 2nd shirt is choosing it at random from 2 posible shirts, that is $\frac12$. Hence $\mathcal P(X_{n+1}=2, X_n=1)=\frac13\times\frac12$

Notice that this reasoning (of computing $\mathcal P(X_{n+1}|X_n)=\frac{\mathcal P(X_{n+1},X_n)}{\mathcal P(X_n)}$) is possible thanks to the fact that our initial distribution is the stationary distribution. Had the initial distribution been $\pi_0=(\frac12,\frac18,\frac38)$, we would have to make a much more complicated argument.

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering if it were possible to figure out what a Venn diagram of the event {X$_{n+1}$ =2} $\cap$ {X$_n$=1} would look like.

Comment: In general $\mathcal P \{X_n=x\}$ is not easy to calculate. Say we want to figure out $\mathcal P \{X_n=1\}$. Given the nature of the problem, we know that the shirt worn during the $n$-th day depends on what was worn the previous day, so
$\mathcal P \{X_n=1\} = \mathcal P \{X_n=x|X_{n-1}=2\}\mathcal P \{X_{n-1}=2\}+\mathcal P \{X_n=1|X_{n-1}=3\}\mathcal P \{X_{n-1}=3\}$
But we know that the shirt worn during the $n-1$-th day depends on what was worn the previous day, and so on. You can see that this will get nasty without any additional conditions.

Comment: Things get a lot easier when you can work without taking into account time, and that's precisely what stationary distributions do. Venn diagrams and Markov chains don't get along, basically because you have an infinite number of possible events. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Doesn't the conditional probability $P(X|Y=y)$ mean the probability of X occurring given that Y has occurred? Here, we have been told that the man has chosen the first shirt. Surely, then given that shirts 2 and 3 are chosen equally likely, shouldn't the probability of choosing shirt 2 be $\frac{1}{2}$ irrespective of what the probability of choosing shirt 1? All that matters is that we know shirt 1 has been chosen, and that we know that we will choose either shirt 2 or shirt 3. What would the probability $P(X_{n+1}=2|X_n=1)$ be if the probability of shirt 1 being chosen was, say 1?

Comment: @jim Sorry for the late response. You're completely right: $\mathcal P(X_{n+1} =2|X_n=1) =\frac12$. As you've pointed out, it suffices to consider the nature of the problem. Now, when you try to use the usual definition of conditional probability, you need to calculate $\mathcal P(X_n=1)$, which I've tried to argue that it isn't quite easy to calculate without previous knowledge.